# Prevent access to another user using Grails SpringSecutiryCore

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have the following questions,
How do I prevent a user to access another using the SpringSecurityCore?

For example, prevent a student to access data from another student. At the time the two have the same role (role student)
and if I do ***student/show/1*** I can see and edit the data. I want to stop it!

I can do with the ACL plugin, using the @PreAuthorize tag but it is deprecated and is giving error with the 2.5.1 version of Grails.

Following as it did in ACL: Only the ADMIN and the student logged in have access.

```
@PreAuthorize("(hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')) or (isAuthenticated()) and (principal.id==#studentInstance.id)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@Secured](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/requestMappings.html#securedAnnotations) annotation at the method level instead. Then compare the principal ID like you're already doing. Finally, [render](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/ref/Controllers/render.html) a 403 status when the principal doesn't match.

```
render(status: 503)
```

Comment: LOL! It happens to all of us.